docker - install python-pip on php-fpm-alpine is extremely slow
I'm trying to install python-pip on my app
FROM php:7.2-fpm
....
RUN apt-get install -y python-pip

This is taking more than 2 hours and its still not complete. Checking htop it shows no problem om RAM or Disk consume.
I found an article saying that Linux Alpine has a problem related to Python: https://pythonspeed.com/articles/alpine-docker-python/
So, is there any way to make this install faster?
Or is there any way to use php-fpm image without Alpine?

Why are you trying to use a Python package manager in a PHP-based image?  (An outdated one, too: as of this writing it looks like the php image includes only 8.1 and later maintained tags.)  If you have a Python piece, can you run it in a separate image built FROM python?

@DavidMaze I need to run node-sass to compile files after composer-install. and node-sass requires python... just for this purpose

I'm not well familiar with php, but speaking of suitable image for python, I suggest you to use Slim Docker image instead of alpine.
Alpine is indeed a small in size, but you have to build it from scratch(install all necessary packages, etc), while the slim docker image has already installed all required packages.
Additional source of information about this
